# Is replacing USB serial WITH ESP8266+ESP link feasible?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, esp8266, softwareserial

ESP8266 (01-512k,) Arduino Uno (clone), Arduino IDE, Python 2.7.6 on Macbook pro running OSX 10.10.4 64-bit.

Hello!

I'm using a motion sensor with the following setup:

Arduino Uno+motion sensor >>>sensor values>>>USB Serial>>>Laptop running Python code>>>Notification>>>WiFi>>>Web

The sensor generates a value. The value is displayed on the serial monitor. The python program is triggered into action by a specific value appearing on the serial monitor and the program sends an email notification.

I would like to replace that setup with the following:

Arduino Uno+motion sensor>>>sensor values>>>ESP8266 as transparent WiFi to Serial bridge>>>Laptop running Python code>>>Notification>>>WiFi>>>Web

Essentially, I want to get rid of the USB cable and use the ESP8266 as a transparent WiFi to Serial bridge. Of course, a battery would power the Arduino and ESP8266.

I read [this post](http://hackaday.com/2015/09/18/transparent-esp8266-wifi-to-serial-bridge/)  and the Jeelabs/ ESP Link Readme. It seems that the ESP8266, once flashed with ESP Link, could replace a serial cable. But, can ESP Link replace the USB Serial in my current setup? If so, are there tutorials explaining how this can be done?

I did some further reading and researched the matter but so far I only found one use case similar to what I want to do. In the said use case, a virtual serial connection through WiFi was being executed via a server within the ESP8266. Unfortunately, there were no detailed explanations on how this was achieved and I don't think this would be suitable for my specific use.

Please let me know if further information or clarification is needed.

Comment: Why not use an actual protocol, such as HTTP?

Comment: The jeelabs link is indeed what you are looking for. You no longer need a USB-to-serial for that one (other than to program the ESP the first time).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hello, Would you say that the HTTP protocol would be better than the Jeelabs ESP Link transparent WiFi to serial bridge? If so, for which reasons? Thanks!

Comment: @Gerben Hello, Thank you for your comment. I'll dig deeper into the Jeelabs documentation and forums to determine the best way to go about it and report back here with progress or a solution. If you have any tips please feel free to post them. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of motion sensor are you using? You might be able to use an ESP8266 directly with it.

Comment: @Pabluski Hello, For this project it's a standard PIR motion sensor. I thought about having everything on the ESP8266 but first I need to understand the ESP8266 a bit better. Thanks!